# OrCAD Capture Test Point

Tags: symbol, orcad

Does OrCAD Capture carry a test point part in an inbuilt library to be used in a schematic?

Comment: Not having OrCad installed, I can't pinpoint you to the exact location of a test point part. However, creating a test point part from scratch is probably the simpler approach if you can't find it.

It is a one pin component and all you need is to assign a through hole footprint on the PCB part and you are mostly done. There are a couple tutorials online on how to create parts in OrCAD that you can follow along.

As a note, you will often have to create custom parts since default libraries are often thin.